# Google's Open Sans Regular 400 always italic?

Tags: google-webfonts, text-rendering

It seems that Google is now serving Open Sans Regular 400 as italic. Anyone else experiencing the same issue?

Preview tools from various websites suggest the same. This screenshot is from http://typecast.com/preview/google/Open%20Sans

[image: from typecast.com]

Comment: Seems to be a chrome specific issue. Investigating further

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the reason for the issue:

I had installed *some* of Google's Open Sans font styles (Bold, Bold Italic, Italic, etc), but not Regular 400, using the service called SkyFonts.

When any website offered to serve a webfont-version of Open Sans, Chrome obviously resolved to using the system font Open Sans, falling back to 400 italic, which was the closest to 400 Regular, rather than downloading the webfonts.

Internet Explorer was not handling the issue the same way, and managed thus to present the webfont instead of using the closest matched system font.

#### Solution

The solution was one of the following:

1. Remove all locally installed Open Sans font variations
2. Install the missing 400 regular font variation in addition to those already there

Comment: Removing them worked for me with Archivo. I had all the correct font variations installed but it was still using the italic variation. I'm on `Ubuntu 17.04`